# How do I put in a progress bar with custom images at the 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, and 100% marks?

Tags: swift, xcode, progress-bar

I'm trying to make the loading (launch) screen for an app and I created images that shows a loading bar at 20%, 40%, etc. and I want to know how I can switch to the desired image when the load progress reaches the specified amount. I'm new to Xcode and I still need to learn a lot of the syntax and variables associated with Swift, so any help would be appreciated!

Here are the images used to display loading progress on the launch screen.

[Progress bar at 20%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTizb.png)

[Progress bar at 40%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IcZc.png)

[Progress bar at 60%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdnh2.png)

[Progress bar at 80%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QKjG.png)

[Progress bar at 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJheD.png)

Comment: If you are loading JSON data with known amount of elements. Provided your backend JSON returned using pagination, you could easily calculate downloading percentage from the JSON data and display on your loading bar.

Comment: If you are downloading an image or a file. simply calculate percentage between the bytes you have been downloaded and overall size of your file, then display the loading bar percentage accordingly.